# Ionic package build failed - ionic-plugin-keyboard

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an app that works fine in ionic serve. I am now trying to create a build -- this normally works but today I am running into problems.

```
ionic package build ios --profile development
```

This gives me a success message.

```
Uploading your project to Ionic...
Submitting your app to Ionic Package...
Your app has been successfully submitted to Ionic Package!
Build ID: 103
We are now packaging your app.
```

But when I check the app in Ionic Package I see that the build failed. There is just one error:

```
In file included from /Users/package/workspace/apps-96ff266e-5/cordova/platforms/ios/wurkclient/Plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/IonicKeyboard.m:1:
/Users/package/workspace/apps-96ff266e-5/cordova/platforms/ios/wurkclient/Plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/IonicKeyboard.h:8:5: error: unknown type name 'Method'
    Method wkMethod, uiMethod;
    ^
```

My ionic info output is:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.46
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

I have tried the ionic platform remove ios and then the ionic platform add ios but no improvements.

I am out of ideas!

Comment: I unfortunately have no experience with Ionic Cloud. If you have a Mac, you can build your app using the `ionic build ios` command. Another possibility is to open `appname.xcodeproj` in the platforms/ios folder in XCode and build it there with XCode.

Comment: Just going to leave this here -  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-package-build-ios-fails-with-error-in-ionic-keyboard/81397/10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue with Ionic's servers - seems to be an after effect of the AWS downtime earlier in the week. All good now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a very common issue, just try to remove node_modules and plugins folder and use below command to build the project again. This worked for me!

ionic build

Android

> `ionic cordova build ios --prod`

iOS

> `ionic cordova build android --prod`

Answer (score 0):

For android >>
`npm run ionic:build --prod
cordova build android --prod`

For iOS >>
`npm run ionic:build --prod
cordova build ios  --prod`